# Display data from post() Methods in Bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery

I'm trying with my code to get Bootstrap popover showing and displaying my data, But my popover it won't showing. can anyone see if somethings wrong with my code, thanks in advance!

**Html**

```
<a class="page" href="#" id="<?php echo $objResult["page"]; ?>" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="">Show</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.page').popover({"trigger": "manual", "html":"true"});
    $('.page').on('click', get_popover);

    get_popover = function() {
        var page_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var text = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getmemberview.php',
            data: ({pageid: page_id}),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                 text.attr('data-content', data);
                 text.popover('show');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: do you get any error in console?

Comment: @shershen No my friend, But my popover doesn't show.

Comment: is your ajax triggering?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on that line - '   text.attr('data-content', data);' does it get there? I mean is the network call successful ?

Comment: I suppose that 'data' you're getting in the **success: function (data) {** is not a plain text, but an object, smth like - data.some_property

Comment: @shershen Okay, I'll check it out